# Is there a way to customize the text content of Google One Tap prompt?

Tags: google-signin, google-one-tap

Our application has a multi-tenant architecture where we have multiple different websites deployed using a single codebase. Is there a way to edit the application name (ie. show `Sign in to <Website 1> with Google` instead of `Sign in to <App name> with Google`) without needing to create a separate project in Google Console for each website?

If editing the app name is impossible, is there a way to just show `Sign in with Google` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Google allows you to do that, basically due to some legal/UX concerns. Take below UX as an example.

1. Users go to website1, and see prompt for "App Name 1". Then grant it.
2. Users go to website2, and see prompt for "App Name 2". And it'd be a big surprise, to some of them, that the permission has arleady been granted. Users may think 1)Google granted it without user's consent, or 2) someone had stolen his credentials and granted it, etc.

In summary, you need to make a decision first:

1. if you think end users should treat your different origins as different apps, you should create different projects for them(, so that their UX are isolated from each others).
2. if you think users should treat your different origins as a single app, then using same app name is not an issue at all.